# Oracle allows duplicated records even if there is Primary key and Unique index

Tags: oracle

I am using OracleBulkCopy to insert records into an Oracle database in batches of 3. In my table, duplicated records are inserted for the first batch, but fail for the next. The first batch should fail as well since it should not allow duplicated entries! Below you may find my table 'create script' (I have removed some of the fields).

Any ideas?

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table CHEQUES
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES" 
   (    "RECORDID" NUMBER(38,2), 
    "CHEQUE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "SCANNING_DATE" VARCHAR2(19 CHAR), 
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 LOB ("MSGNUMBERS") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 LOB ("DOCSTYPE") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 LOB ("DOCSPAGESTYPE") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 LOB ("IMAGESLINK") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) 
 LOB ("IMAGES") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index CHEQUES_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES_PK" ON "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES" ("RECORDID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
  ALTER INDEX "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES_PK"  UNUSABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table CHEQUES
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES" ADD CONSTRAINT "CHEQUES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("RECORDID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
  ALTER INDEX "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES_PK"  UNUSABLE; ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "DBOUSB"."CHEQUES" MODIFY ("RECORDID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Comment: There's no need to put any index on a column that you're going to add a primary key constraint on later - the primary key constraint will add a unique index automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the trouble lying in the fact that your `cheques_pk` index is in the `unusable` state.

Comment: It becomes unusable after the first batch instert of the OracleBulkCopy. OracleBulkCopy disables the index and makes it unusable, and then on the second batch since the index is already unusable it throws an error. What I'm trying to achieve is to disable the first insert so the index won't become unusable.